# Constructores copia y destructores en C++98

Tags: c++, c++98

Esto es una pequeña envoltura para un sistema de bitácoras; la librería utilizada está en C, así que simplemente le he añadido un interfaz *a lo `std::stream`*:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class ILogger;

class Stream {
  friend class ::ILogger;

  std::stringstream m_ss;

  Stream( const Stream & );
  Stream &operator=( const Stream & );

public:
  ~Stream( ) {
    std::cout << m_ss.str( ) << std::endl;
  }
  inline Stream( ) { }

  template< typename T > inline Stream &operator<<( const T &val ) {
    m_ss << val;

    return *this;
  }
};

class ILogger {
public:
  template< typename T > inline Stream operator<<( const T &val ) {
    Stream s;

    s << val;

    return s;
  }
};

int main( ) {
  ILogger log;

  log << "Hola" << " mundo " << "cruel";

  return 0;
}
```

La librería utiliza funciones *a lo `printf`*, así que nos limitamos a generar una cadena mediante un `std::stringstream` mediante una clase auxiliar y, **al destruir** la instancia de esa auxiliar, es cuando se llama a la verdadera función de C.

Para mi sorpresa, el código ¡ funciona !

Digo esto porque yo esperaba un error de compilación, al tener `Stream::Stream( const Stream & )` declarado como `private`. Esperaba que, al salir del ámbito, se invocara al constructor copia y al destructor. Aún no lo he dicho, pero esto es para C++98.

```
template< typename T > inline Stream operator<<( const T &val ) {
  Stream s;

  s << val;

  return s; // salimos del ámbito. 's' se pierde
}
```

Estoy compilando con `g++ 7.2`, con la orden `g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

- La pregunta es: ¿ Esto es el comportamiento esperado, o es una *característica* de mi compilador ? ¿ Puedo confiar es obtener los mismos resultados en compiladores mas antigos ?

<sub>**Nota**: El objetivo de ese código es ejecutarse en máquinas muy antiguas, con SDK ya sin soporte ... y no quiero sorpresas de última hora :-O</sub>

Answer (score 4):

¿Dónde está la sorpresa? ¡para eso están los amigos!

```
class Stream {
  friend class ::ILogger;

  /* codigo */
}
```

Al tener `Stream` como amiga `ILogger`, ésta tendrá acceso incluso a las secciones privadas de `Stream`, tanto las variables, como las funciones, incluidas las funciones especiales.

> ¿ Esto es el comportamiento esperado, o es una *característica* de mi compilador ?

No es una característica de compilador, es una característica intrinseca del lenguaje, lo indica el estándar en la sección 14.3 (traducción mía):

> #### 14.3 Amigos [class.friend]
>
> 1. La amiga de una clase es una función o clase a la que se le otorgan permisos para usar los miembros privados y protegidos de dicha clase. Una clase especifica sus amigos, si los hay, mediante declaraciones de amigos. Estas declaraciones dan derechos especiales de acceso a los maigos, pero no hacen que los amigos sean miembros de las clases con las que tienen amistad.

> ¿ Puedo confiar es obtener los mismos resultados en compiladores mas antigos ?

Si. El siguiente código se comporta como el tuyo:

```
class C
{
    friend struct X;
    void privada() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
public:
    void publica() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

struct X
{
    /* X puede usar C::privada, porque C se lo permite
    con su amistad. */
    void f() { C c; c.privada(); }
};
```

Y esto falla:

```
struct Y
{
    /* Error de compilación, Y no puede usar C::privada
    porque C no le otorgó amistad. */
    void f() { C c; c.privada(); }
};
```

> Esperaba que, al salir del ámbito, se invocara al constructor copia y al destructor.

Esto es así en algunos casos, y en otros el compilador aplica una optimización conocida como "Optimización del Valor de Retorno" (OVR)<sup>1</sup>, esta optimización consiste en que el compilador puede decidir construir un objeto fuera de la función que lo crea si detecta que haciendo esto no provoca ningún efecto secundario, omitiendo así una copia. Esta optimización lleva integrada en el lenguaje casi desde el principio, así que en C++98 está disponible.

Posiblmente obtengas el comportamiento que esperabas si desactivas todas las optimizaciones de tu compilador.

---

1. Conocida en inglés como "Return Value Optimization" RVO.

Comment: ¡ Pues ahora estoy aún mas sorprendido ! Ok. Se llama al constructor copia y al destructor. Entonces, al ejecutarlo, ¿ no deberían de salir **2 líneas** de texto ? Sin embargo, sale solo una. Y yo no le pongo cuerpo al constructor, y declaro mas de 1. ¿ El compilador lo crea por mi, aún en esas condiciones ?

Comment: Desactiva todas las optimizaiones y saldrán todas tus líneas de texto (te está haciendo optimización del valor de retorno). El compilador, efectivamente, crea (bajo ciertas circunstancias) las funciones especiales que el programador no crea.

Comment: Lo único que faltaría comentar es que `str` **puede** lanzar excepciones (raro, pero puede pasar si, por ejemplo, no puede hacer la reserva de memoria). En ese caso fallará la destrucción de `Stream` y eso puede provocar fugas de memoria... a mi modo de ver hay que evitar que los destructores lancen excepciones

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus pon lo de RVO en la respuesta, que era mi preocupación principal. El 'friend' está ahí por error ... Inicié con otra idea en mente, que cambié sobre la marcha, y lo olvidé !! Pero lo que me escamaba era que imprimiera 1 sola línea ...